# Any iOS core lib can upload blob to windows azure storage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-storage

Windows azure SDK-ios only for mobileService,I want to upload something to storage in iOS app.

Have any core lib to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this walkthrough: http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage.  It details how to use Mobile Services to generate a Secure Access Signature which you can hand back to your iOS app to use to upload to blob storage.  This prevents you from needing to keep the storage account name and key in your client application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UIImage *img = self.imageItem.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

    NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: {replace with the storage url you are uploading to}  ] ];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"PUT"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: imageData];
    [theRequest setValue:@"image/PNG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"BlockBlob"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-ms-blob-type"];
    [theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    NSData *response;
    NSError *WSerror;
    NSURLResponse *WSresponse;
    NSString *responseString;
    response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

Comment: not working.. I think it has an Authorization Header